# Trying to scrape conversion value from a website, why is 'undefined' value returned in the Data Layer?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-tag-manager

I have implemented facebook event tracking on my company's website using Google Tag Manager. We want to begin recording the conversion value whenever a user initiates a checkout on our website, and after the checkout is complete.

When testing the code retrieved from an extension (GTM Variable Builder) in Chrome's inspect console tool, it gives the correct output. This tells me that the code is right at least in part, and makes me think that it is executing in the wrong order, or is being overridden.

When I use catch(e) to return a different response in case of error, this provides my chosen output, so I don't believe it is being overridden.

Thinking that the code would work after the page loads, I used `(window).load(function)`. See the following code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    try{
    return new document.querySelectorAll(".container-wrap>.container.main-      content>.row>#fws_5dbcb43a4c51c>.col.span_12.dark.left>.vc_col-sm-12.wpb_column.column_container.vc_column_container.col.no-extra-padding.instance-0>.vc_column-inner>.wpb_wrapper>.arv_row>.arv_col.arv_span_9>.arv_rowinfo.clearfix>.arv_desc.arv_row.clearfix>.arv_info.arv_col.arv_span_8.arv_col_last>.arv_extra>#rentalForm>.arv_calcrow.clearfix>.arv_calcrow_p")[3].innerText.match(/^.{1}(.*).{0}/i)[1].trim();}
    catch(e) {
            return "Well at least you tried";
    }
})
```

The string of code still returns 'undefined'. I expect it to provide the value that this string of code points to when the page is already loaded.

Comment: I have trouble understanding the question. Datalayer is a specific concept in GTM, which you are not using. If you want to scrape a DOM element in GTM, use the DOM Element type variable, the values will be accessible in all tags that are fired after "DOM Ready".

Comment: Sorry, I am very inexperienced, which makes it hard to explain the problem. The problem I am facing is that the element I'm trying to select has no ID and the class appears multiple times on the page. I am unable to select the specific element to return its value in the data layer (because I can't figure it out.) The value I am trying to get is a total cart value during a checkout process. If there is a way to ensure that I select the last shown element for its class on the page, I could likely return the correct value. I am not sure if there is a better way to approach this.

Comment: There is a variable in GTM called "dataLayer" (an array of objects), but your code does push a value to that dataLayer array, which makes me suspect you are using the term incorrectly. Also you would use an "pageload" trigger rather than assigning your own event handlers.